# Pass 2D array from C# to Postgresql function

Tags: c#, arrays, postgresql, sqlcommand

Here is postgresql running query with pg admin iii. (Below query working fine with pg admin and it is returning result set without any issue)

```
select * from  pg_sp_getmainrates_11(9,10,array[[5,10,10,10],[30,20,15,16]]);
```

Here is parameter declaration of pg function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_sp_getmainrates_11(
    IN fromcountryid integer,
    IN tocountryid integer,    
    IN alldimensions_we_le_he_wi double precision[]
   )

-- My logic is going here
```

But when passing array using C# code, it is returning error when executing the query.

Exeption attributes

Basemessage : syntax error at or near ","

ErrorSql : SELECT * FROM pg_sp_getmainrates_11(9,10,System.Double[,])

Here is my C# code.

```
   double[,] codes = new double[,]
    {
        { 5,10,10,10},{ 30,20,15,16}
    };

  string quy = "pg_sp_getmainrates_11(" + FromCountryId +
                               "," + ToCountryId +
                               "," + codes + ")";

        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(quy, conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
```

I need a small direction to pass an array (like above) to my postgresql function.

Comment: your c# array is: `{{},{}}`  your postgresql array is: `[[],[]]` . No one will convert it for you if you won't tell the compiler to do such conversion. More over postgresql does not treat the same for `array` and `int[]` or `numeric[]`. you may call them the same but they are not the same. So your definition for array in c# as double[,] needs to be casted for the proper type in postgresql.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943106/how-to-do-a-postgresql-query-with-where-in-clause-which-contains-multiple-column/58485204#58485204

Answer (score 1):

Up to now I found a solution for this. (Don't know whether this is the optimum solution)
The simple thing to send parameter as string.
With my C# code I make some string like below.

```
String arr = "array[[5,10,10,10],[30,20,15,16]]";
```

This arr will be passed as query parameter.

```
string quy = "pg_sp_getmainrates_11(" + FromCountryId +
                               "," + ToCountryId +
                               "," + arr+ ")";
```

Above solution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `using Newtonsoft.Json;` and insert your array like the following:

```
string[][] arr = {{5, 10, 10, 10},{30, 20, 15, 16}};
var arrayOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr);

try
{
    string sql1 = "INSERT INTO tbt(img, fcth, dev) VALUES (ARRAY'" + arrayOutput + "')";
    dbcmd.CommandText = sql1;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

catch (NpgsqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Data == null)
    {
        throw;
    }

    else
    {
    }

}
```

This example Just for array column.