# How to do a PostgreSQL query with where-in clause which contains multiple columns programmatically?

Tags: java, c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

My query is like this:

```
select * from plat_customs_complex
where (code_t,code_s) 
in (('01013090','10'),('01029010','90'));
```

It runs well in psql console. My question is how to perform this query in client code.(via C# or Java)

And I already know the following code works well(C#):

```
string[] codeT = new string[]{"01013090","01029010"};    
connection.Query("SELECT * FROM plat_customs_complex WHERE code_t=ANY(@CodeT)",
new { CodeT = codeT });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the `unnest` function can help.

Pure SQL is like that:

```
select * from plat_customs_complex
where (code_t,code_s) = ANY(select * from unnest(ARRAY['01013090','01029010'],ARRAY['10','90']))
```

Can convert it to C# code easily:

```
string[] codeTs = new string[]{"01013090","01029010"}; 
string[] codeSs = new string[]{"10", "90"};
connection.Query("select * from plat_customs_complex
where (code_t,code_s) = ANY(select * from unnest(@CodeTs, @CodeSs))", 
new {CodeTs=codeTs, CodeSs=codeSs});
```